# react Dispatcher.dispatch in action, not dispatching payload to store

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I have setup payload in "action", with the intention to dispatch api data to the store. But switch case is not triggered inside Dispatcher.register.

Flux version: "flux": "^2.1.1",

1) action file: (note: have confirmed that receivedAllServices is triggered by using debugger )

```
"use strict"

var Dispatcher = require('../dispatcher/appDispatcher');
// var requestActions = require('./requestActions');
var ActionTypes = require('../constants/actionTypes');

var ResponseActions = {

    receivedAllServices: function(all_services){

        console.log('response received');
        debugger;

        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType: ActionTypes.RECEIVED_ALL_SERVICES,
            services: all_servicess
        });
    }



};

module.exports = ResponseActions;
```

2) Store: (note: debugger inside store action is not triggered )

```
Dispatcher.register(function(action){
    switch(action.actionType){
        case ActionTypes.RECEIVED_ALL_SERVICES:

            debugger;

            // AuthorStore.emitChange();
            break;
    }
});
```

3) Dispatcher file:

```
var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;

module.exports = new Dispatcher();
```

4) actionTypes.js file

```
"use strict"

var keyMirror = require('fbjs/lib/keyMirror');

module.exports = keyMirror({
    RECEIVED_ALL_SERVICES: null, 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it's strange. Everything looks correct. Can you check that `Dispatcher` in `store.js` and `action.js` are same objects?

See below the short example with the same action/store. All works correct (press `run` and see the console output).

```js
var appDispatcher = new Flux.Dispatcher();

// This code should be our action
function receivedAllServices() {
  appDispatcher.dispatch({
    actionType: 'RECEIVED_ALL_SERVICES',
    services: ['serv1','serv2'],
  });
  console.log('Done');
}


// This code should be our store
appDispatcher.register(action => {
  console.log('action', action);
  switch(action.actionType){
    case 'RECEIVED_ALL_SERVICES':
      //debugger;
      // AuthorStore.emitChange();
      console.log('AuthorStore.emitChange');
      break;
  }
});

// Call the action
receivedAllServices();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flux/2.1.1/Flux.js"></script>
```